# jQuery animate percent number?

Tags: jquery

Ive looked all over but I cant find how to use jQuery's .animate() function to animate a percentage I have.

I have a progress bar with a percent number above it. When the page loads I simply want the number to increase from 0 to a defined number lets say 67%. How do I animate the number so that it displays as 1%, 2%, 3% ...up to 67%?

Also something to note is I would like to use jQuery's .animate() function because I want to define the time it takes to get to 67%.

Comment: You want to animate... a number? jQuery's animate function moves elements and changes their properties. It doesn't change text. You have to code that on your own.

Comment: .animate() animates css properties , not numbers. In simple words, not possible. You may however want to try setTimeout or setInterval

Answer (score 2):

You can do this right inside the animate function, using the `step` property. Something like so:

```
  $(elem).animate({
        width : '200px' //whatever your bar animation consists of
  }, {
        step  : function(now, fx){
             //use the 'now' to calculate percent and update the number
             $(percentElem).text(now / 200);
        }
  }, 2000); // set duration
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be beter to make your own function. I can suggest one.

```
window.loadBar = {
    startTime: null,
    time: 500,
    updater: null
}
function loadBarStart(){
    loadBar.startTime = new Date();
    loadBar.updater = function(){
       var delta = (new Date() - loadBar.startTime)/loadBar.time;
       $("#bar").html((delta*100)+"%");
       if(delta<1)window.setTimenout(loadBar.updater, 30);
    }
    loadBar.updater();
}
```

I've don't test it, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, what you want is to use `$('#element').html(data)` getting `data` from a real source or using a timer. The progress bar usually is done by plugging dynamically that number as the width of your progress bar.

Comment: I've done the progress bar. No need to worry about that. Its just this percentage animation I cant seem to find any info on.

Comment: As Juhana and Jashwatn said, you can't do that by using .animate. That's why I suggested a way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you love to write code from scratch, check this out: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Once you have that progress bar initialized, you "animate" it like so:

```
$('#yourBar').progressbar( "value" , 55 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution based on the previous answers. In this case "percentage" is a global variable that it being set before the function is called. Play with the decimal added to the value and the setTimeout ms to change the behavior.

```
function animateProgress() {
    var value = $("#progress").progressbar( "option", "value" );

    if ( value < percentage ) {
        value = value+.5;
    } else if ( percentage < value ) {
        value = value-.5;
    }

    $("#progress").progressbar( "option", "value", value );
    $('#readout').html( value+' - '+percentage+'%' );
    if ( value != percentage ) {
        setTimeout( function(){ animateProgress(); }, 2 );
    }
}
```